# How to take device-screenshot in Android Studio 2.4

Tags: android-studio, screenshot

In Studio 2.3 (current stable) we can get a device-screenshot via "Android Monitor" just like in the docs.

https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-screenshot.html

But in Studio 2.4 (using Preview 6) this option is missing.

---

It seems that there are some new windows instead of "Android Monitor" ("Android Profiler", "Device File Manager") but I can't find the option to take a screenshot / video.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The screenshot action is moved to the logcat Toolwindow

Answer (score 1):

As an addition to LE GALL Benoit's answer:

[image: logcat window]